# Why are App Engine instances shutting down with a "start" message?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am getting a lot of these errors in my App Engine Standard Environment Python 3 application. The application seems to initialize and to work fine: I can't see any sort of failure during initialization.

How can I figure out the cause? Could it be ordinary instance scale-down  despite what this log says?

```
 Start program failed: termination triggered by nginx exit

 [INFO] Shutting down: Master 
 Worker exiting (pid: 20)

 [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
 Handling signal: term

 Quitting on terminated signal
```

I see a number of these shut-down errors in a row, suggesting that multiple instances are shutting down. So, the last step from 1 to 0 instances is not the relevant one.

The `app.yaml` is as follows:

```
runtime: python39
service: iris3

env_variables:
  TOKENPS: 54
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of you App.yaml, maybe there is a configuration error, for example with **min_instances** option

Comment: I added it to the bottom of the question body.

Comment: I've made some research and the most common root cause for that error are scaling configurations in the app.yaml. Can you try to use `min_instances: 1` in your yaml file? Here is the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#scaling_elements) if you have doubts about other scaling options. if this works for you please tell me

Comment: Thank you. However, I would like to use AppEngine's scale-to-zero feature. Do these lines really indicate a problem. Some discussions hint that this might be ordinary shutdowns as part of scaledown and not a crash during initialization as the log says. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323488  Could you send  link to what your research found? I am not finding much.

Comment: Also, I see a number of these shut-down errors in a row, suggesting that multiple instances are shutting down. So, the last step from 1 to 0 instances is not the relevant one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested a Hello World example and found that this is the ordinary log during  instance scaledown.

The log should be considered a bug. It clearly says that **start** -- i.e., initialization -- is failing, where in fact nothing  is failing and this involves shutdown rather than startup.

Comment: Just continue to investigate, I found that also the runtime has a [bug](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1458)  when returning a 204, maybe this is the real root cause. If you could plase share your Hello World experiment it could be awesome to try and replicate.

Comment: I just took the standard Hello World in Python, added `time.sleep(10)`  in the request method, hit it with curl in 100 parallel processes. That's it. Of course App Engine added more instances, then scaled down.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you return a status of 204 it can shut down your instance,
It's a kind of bug in gunicorn, you can see [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1458)

Answer (score -1):

This is an expected behavior, the instances began to [shut down](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown) in response to some events, like exceeding the number of idle instances and they are no longer processing requests.

That log messages correspond to [SIGTERM](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build#application_shutdown) signals sended by the GAE environment to the app container. The full log messages represents the steps taken to terminate all processes and the instance

Comment: Certainly, shutdown is expected behavior, as stated in the question. But messages saying that there was a *failure*, and worse, that the failure was in *initialization* ("Start") are highly misleading.