# Deploy Java 11 Maven SpringBoot on AppEngine Fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy my Applicaiton on spring boot but when I made, service returns 500 and logs only show that:
[image]

I'm trying with the tutorial off GPC: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-springboot#0
But it doesnt work and the logs are not clear that what is going wrong, if any one can help me I will appreciate.

My appengine/app.yaml

```
runtime: java11
env: standard
runtime_config:
  jdk: openjdk11
env_variables:
  SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: "dev"
handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

My mainclass:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.softlond</groupId>
    <artifactId>foodtech_backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Base Softlond</name>
    <description>Base preconfigurada para softlond</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.106</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
            <version>0.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
            <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
            <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>WAR</layout>
                    <addResources>true</addResources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Could you try to run **gcloud app logs tail** to see if it shows the same logs?

Comment: Hi Catherine, yes is show me the same log

Comment: Based from your logs, it's not clearly shown as to what triggers the error aside from the instance being shutdown since there was no incoming requests. You may want to try to increase your max instances as 1 is not considered as best practice as also mentioned in this stack [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61323488/google-app-engine-restarting-automatically-randomly/61349165#61349165). @Daniel ORTIZ

Comment: I do, but the result is the same, i think is something belong to war config

Comment: The logs you've provided looks normal to me and don't show any trace of HTTP 500 error encountered. However, possible cause of HTTP 500 error can be port issue, instance start up etc.